# Issues with cin and setting a class variabe

Tags: c++

I'm currently delving into C++ for the first time; I am looking to set the 'playerName' from  user input so I have the following code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Player
{
private:
        char* playerName;
    double playerBalance;


public:
    Player();

    ~Player();

    //getters
    char* getName(void);
    double getBalance(void);

    //setters
    void setName()
    {
        cout << "Please enter your name: ";
        cin >>  playerName;
    }
    void setBalance()
    {
        cout << "Please enter a player balance: ";
        cin >> playerBalance;
    }
};
```

I am calling both set balance and name like so:

```
Player instance
instance.setBalance();
cout << instance.getBalance() << endl;  //Test for input
instance.setName();
```

It will accept the playerBalance value and curn it back out however it won't allow the same with playerName

Thanks in advance it may just be my lack of understanding or a syntactical error right now I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `cin` with a char pointer unless it already points to a char array. Two ways to fix:

1. Use `std::string playerName` instead of a char pointer. This is the preferred way because that way, the length of your players' names is not limited arbitrarily. (It may also help you avoid a buffer overflow vulnerability if you are not careful with your char*'s.)
2. In your constructor, add `playerName = new char[NAME_LENGTH_MAX];` so that the char* points to a char array.

Also, shouldn't your setters take a value? For example, in the Player class:

```
void setName(std::string newName)
{
    playerName = newName;
}
```

And in the client class:

```
Player instance;
std::string nameFromUser;
cin >> nameFromUser;
instance.setName(nameFromUser);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a followup if possible, when adding: playerName = new char[NAME_LENGTH_MAX], I get the error; " identifier "NAME_LENGHT_MAX" is undefined"


Do I have to include something into the player.cpp constuctor

Comment: That is where you set the maximum length of the name. Ideally you would use a constant, as the length limit will affect how other parts of your code work (i.e. validating input). However, I suggest that you do not use a character array because you most likely do not need that kind of performance. Just use an `std::string` and make your life easier.